# REST Server without GUI

Tags: rest, delphi

I've started working with delphi quite some while ago but I would say I'm still a newbie in all this.
So basically I tried creating REST Server, which can validate license keys. I got in working with Indy, but one thing bothers me. The GUI. The Server shouldn't have any kind of gui so it can work on any OS (Win, Linux, etc). Is there a way to make a REST Server without any GUI/FMX/VCL?

BTW: Working in Delphi 10.2.3 Professional.

Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention one thing: the server is supposed to run on an independent Data Center away from any user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean with GUI of the REST server? Perhaps you could check [this video demo](https://chapmanworld.com/2018/08/14/building-rest-services-with-rad-server-delphi-c-builder/). It covers both the services creation and the code on the UI side.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Okay, sorry. I basically only found ways to create a REST server by using TIdTCPServer/TIdHTTPServer or DataSnap. As I can't use DataSnap because it's only available to developer with delphi enterprise or higher, I used Indy(TIdTCPServer) but that has to be put onto a GUI (In my case a FMX GUI), which makes it dependent on FMX. Is that wrong?

Comment: You don't need any UI to use a `TIdTCPServer`. Maybe you are misguided by the drag and drop UI designer. You can create a `TIdTCPServer` just as well directly in code: `var...MyServer: TIdTCPServer;...MyServer := TIdTCPServer.Create(...); ...`

Comment: @TomBrunberg You're kidding me, right? In every example, guide etc they said you have to use a UI for it to work and because I'm relativly new to delphi I took it as it is... Okay I greatly thank you for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the WebServer as a Windows Service.
You can use [DelphiMVCFramework](https://github.com/danieleteti/delphimvcframework) or any other Framework to create it.

- With DMVC you can create console application, Windows Service, Linux daemon, Apache module (Windows and Linux) and IIS ISAPI (Windows).

With [Intraweb](https://doc.atozed.com/en/iw15/deploy/targets/sa/service/) you can also create Services.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering. Do you maybe have any more documentation or something like that? Anything that I can use to learn about that some more?

Comment: Wouldn't that make it just local? I forgot to mention, that the REST Server would be on another Computer/Server and Clients can be installed everywhere. The Server basically gets a License Key, and then has to check if it's already used/valid/max uses reached etc.

Comment: I have updated some information about DMVC.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at our [mORMot Open Source REST framework](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot), which works on Delphi but also on FPC/Lazarus.

FPC support ensures that you can target Linux with this free compiler.  No need to upgrade to a newer version of Delphi Architect, which supports Linux, and is very pricey - and less stable (to my knowledge) since Linux support is quite new.

As you requested, the mORMot REST server has no UI part. You define your services as `interface` and `class` - like you do e.g. with DotNet - and you will have full JSON/REST support generated.

*mORMot* is used on production since years for very high performance and stability, hosted on both Windows and Linux. A [version 2 is on its way](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2), which would be even easier to use for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

And you can create a Windows service or Linux daemon without using any third party framework. Delphi include everything you need. However, it is possible that third party framework will facilitate your programming. Don't forget you'll have to learn those third party framework.

[Creating a Linux daemon service in Delphi](https://chapmanworld.com/2017/04/05/creating-a-linux-daemon-service-in-delphi/)

[Creating a Windows Service in Delphi](https://www.thoughtco.com/creating-windows-service-applications-1058458)

In both cases, you can use the sample code you've found that make use of `TIdTCPServer`.